# OpenXML Issue with CellStyle

Tags: c#, openxml

I'm trying to define a CellStyle within a completly empty spreadsheet. For the CellFormat I use the following code:

```
var workbookStylesPart = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.GetPartsOfType<WorkbookStylesPart>().First();
//create default font for links
Font font2 = new Font();
Underline underline1 = new Underline();
FontSize fontSize2 = new FontSize() { Val = 11D };
Color color2 = new Color() { Theme = (UInt32Value)10U };
FontName fontName2 = new FontName() { Val = "Calibri" };
FontFamilyNumbering fontFamilyNumbering2 = new FontFamilyNumbering() { Val = 2 };
FontScheme fontScheme2 = new FontScheme() { Val = FontSchemeValues.Minor };
font2.Append(underline1);
font2.Append(fontSize2);
font2.Append(color2);
font2.Append(fontName2);
font2.Append(fontFamilyNumbering2);
font2.Append(fontScheme2);

workbookStylesPart.Stylesheet.Fonts.Append(font2);
int fontId = workbookStylesPart.Stylesheet.Fonts.Count() - 1;

CellFormat copy = (CellFormat)workbookStylesPart.Stylesheet.CellFormats.FirstOrDefault().Clone();
copy.FontId = Convert.ToUInt32(fontId);

workbookStylesPart.Stylesheet.CellFormats.Append(copy);
```

This all works fine, I can apply this cellformat to a cell and it is properly formatted, but as soon as I open try to add this to a CellStyle my Spreadsheet is broken and I can't open it anymore. This is how I add the CellStyle:

```
workbookStylesPart.Stylesheet.CellFormats.Append(copy);
int cellFormatId = workbookStylesPart.Stylesheet.CellFormats.Count() - 1;

CellStyle cellStyle2 = new CellStyle() { Name = "linkformat", FormatId = Convert.ToUInt32(cellFormatId), BuiltinId = (UInt32Value)0U };
```

If I change the FormatId back to the value "1U" it works again.
Does anyone have an idea how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

I have applied CellStyle into spreadsheet and it works fine. Please try this:

```
 using (var excel = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(memoryStream, DocumentFormat.OpenXml.SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook, true))
                {
                    workbookPart = excel.AddWorkbookPart();
                    workbookPart.Workbook = new Workbook();
                    uint sheetId = 1;
                    excel.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Sheets = new Sheets();
                    Sheets sheets = excel.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>();

                    WorkbookStylesPart stylesPart = excel.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorkbookStylesPart>();
                    stylesPart.Stylesheet = GenerateStyleSheet();
                    stylesPart.Stylesheet.Save();

 Worksheet worksheet = new Worksheet();

                        wSheetPart.Worksheet = worksheet;

                        SheetData sheetData = new SheetData();
                        worksheet.Append(sheetData);

 excel.Close();

}
```

Here's the GenerateStyleSheet method:

```
public Stylesheet GenerateStyleSheet()
        {
            return new Stylesheet(
            new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Fonts(
            new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Font(new FontSize() { Val = 11 }, new Color() { Rgb = new HexBinaryValue() { Value = "000000" } }, new FontName() { Val = "Calibri" }),// Index 0 - The default font.
            new Font(new Bold(), new FontSize() { Val = 11 }, new Color() { Rgb = new HexBinaryValue() { Value = "000000" } }, new FontName() { Val = "Calibri" }),  // Index 1 - The bold font.
            new Font(new Italic(), new FontSize() { Val = 11 }, new Color() { Rgb = new HexBinaryValue() { Value = "000000" } }, new FontName() { Val = "Calibri" }),  // Index 2 - The Italic font.
            new Font(new FontSize() { Val = 18 }, new Color() { Rgb = new HexBinaryValue() { Value = "000000" } }, new FontName() { Val = "Calibri" }),  // Index 3 - The Times Roman font. with 16 size
            new Font(new Bold(), new FontSize() { Val = 18 }, new Color() { Rgb = new HexBinaryValue() { Value = "000000" } }, new FontName() { Val = "Calibri" }),  // Index 4 - The Times Roman font. with 16 size
            new Font(new Bold(), new FontSize() { Val = 11 }, new Color() { Rgb = new HexBinaryValue() { Value = "FFFFFF" } }, new FontName() { Val = "Calibri" })  // Index 5 - The bold font.

            ),
            new Fills(
            new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Fill( // Index 0 - The default fill.
            new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.PatternFill() { PatternType = PatternValues.None }),
            new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Fill( // Index 1 - The default fill of gray 125 (required)
            new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.PatternFill() { PatternType = PatternValues.Gray125 }),
            new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Fill( // Index 2 - The yellow fill.
            new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.PatternFill(
            new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.ForegroundColor() { Rgb = new HexBinaryValue() { Value = "FFFFFF00" } }
            )
            { PatternType = PatternValues.Solid }),
            new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Fill( // Index 3 - The Blue fill.
            new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.PatternFill(
            new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.ForegroundColor() { Rgb = new HexBinaryValue() { Value = "8EA9DB" } }
            )
            { PatternType = PatternValues.Solid })
            ),
            new Borders(
            new Border( // Index 0 - The default border.
            new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.LeftBorder(),
            new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.RightBorder(),
            new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.TopBorder(),
            new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.BottomBorder(),
            new DiagonalBorder()),
            new Border( // Index 1 - Applies a Left, Right, Top, Bottom border to a cell
            new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.LeftBorder(
            new Color() { Auto = true }
            )
            { Style = BorderStyleValues.Thin },
            new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.RightBorder(
            new Color() { Auto = true }
            )
            { Style = BorderStyleValues.Thin },
            new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.TopBorder(
            new Color() { Auto = true }
            )
            { Style = BorderStyleValues.Thin },
            new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.BottomBorder(
            new Color() { Auto = true }
            )
            { Style = BorderStyleValues.Thin },
            new DiagonalBorder()),
                   new Border( // Index 1 - Applies a Left, Right, Top, Bottom border to a cell
            new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.LeftBorder(
            new Color() { Auto = true }
            )
            { Style = BorderStyleValues.None },
            new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.RightBorder(
            new Color() { Auto = true }
            )
            { Style = BorderStyleValues.None },
            new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.TopBorder(
            new Color() { Auto = true }
            )
            { Style = BorderStyleValues.None },
            new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.BottomBorder(
            new Color() { Rgb = new HexBinaryValue() { Value = "70AD47" } }
            )
            { Style = BorderStyleValues.Thin },
            new DiagonalBorder())
            ),
            new CellFormats(
            new CellFormat() { FontId = 0, FillId = 0, BorderId = 0 }, // Index 0 - The default cell style. If a cell does not have a style index applied it will use this style combination instead
            new CellFormat() { FontId = 1, FillId = 0, BorderId = 0, ApplyFont = true }, // Index 1 - Bold
            new CellFormat() { FontId = 2, FillId = 0, BorderId = 0, ApplyFont = true }, // Index 2 - Italic
            new CellFormat() { FontId = 3, FillId = 0, BorderId = 0, ApplyFont = true }, // Index 3 - Times Roman
            new CellFormat() { FontId = 0, FillId = 2, BorderId = 0, ApplyFill = true }, // Index 4 - Yellow Fill
            new CellFormat( // Index 5 - Alignment
            new Alignment() { Horizontal = HorizontalAlignmentValues.Center, Vertical = VerticalAlignmentValues.Center }
            )
            { FontId = 0, FillId = 0, BorderId = 0, ApplyAlignment = true },
            new CellFormat() { FontId = 0, FillId = 0, BorderId = 1, ApplyBorder = true }, // Index 6 - Border
             new CellFormat(new Alignment() { Horizontal = HorizontalAlignmentValues.Center, Vertical = VerticalAlignmentValues.Center }) // Index 7 - Alignment
             { FontId = 1, FillId = 0, BorderId = 0, ApplyAlignment = true },

             new CellFormat() { FontId = 4, FillId = 0, BorderId = 0, ApplyFont = true }, // Index 8 - Times Roman
             new CellFormat(new Alignment() { Horizontal = HorizontalAlignmentValues.Center, Vertical = VerticalAlignmentValues.Center }) { FontId = 0, FillId = 0, BorderId = 2, ApplyFont = true }, // Index 9 - Bottom Border with Color 70AD47
             new CellFormat(new Alignment() { Horizontal = HorizontalAlignmentValues.Center, Vertical = VerticalAlignmentValues.Center }) // Index 10 - Alignment
             { FontId = 5, FillId = 3, BorderId = 0, ApplyAlignment = true }


             )
            ); // return
        }
```

I have created a method to add into cell:

```
public void AddToCell(SheetData sheetData, UInt32Value styleIndex, UInt32 uint32rowIndex, string strColumnName, DocumentFormat.OpenXml.EnumValue<CellValues> CellDataType, string strCellValue)
        {
            Row row = new Row() { RowIndex = uint32rowIndex };
            Cell cell = new Cell();

            cell = new Cell() { StyleIndex = styleIndex };
            cell.CellReference = strColumnName + row.RowIndex.ToString();
            cell.DataType = CellDataType;
            cell.CellValue = new CellValue(strCellValue);
            row.AppendChild(cell);

            sheetData.Append(row);
        }
```

Now just call this:

```
  AddToCell(sheetData, 1, 3, "B", CellValues.String, "Model");
```